# order of code execution with wait and notify

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, wait, notify

I research using `wait` and `notify` methods for synchronization.

I wrote small example and don't understand why I see this output:

```
take 1
release 1
release 2
```

my code:

main:

```
public class CustomSemaphoreTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore();
        SendingThread sender = new SendingThread(semaphore);
        RecevingThread receiver = new RecevingThread(semaphore);
        sender.start();
        Thread.sleep(300);
        receiver.start();

    }
}
```

sender:

```
class SendingThread extends Thread {
    volatile Semaphore semaphore = null;
    int count = 1;

    public SendingThread(Semaphore semaphore) {
        this.semaphore = semaphore;
    }

    public void run() {
        this.semaphore.take();
    }
}
```

receiver:

```
class RecevingThread extends Thread {
    volatile Semaphore semaphore = null;
    int count = 1;

    public RecevingThread(Semaphore semaphore) {
        this.semaphore = semaphore;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                this.semaphore.release();
                Thread.sleep(20);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
            // System.out.println("get signal " + count++);
        }
    }
}
```

semaphore:

```
class Semaphore {
    private boolean signal = false;
    int rCount = 1;
    int sCount = 1;

    public synchronized void take() {
        System.out.println("take " + sCount++);
        this.signal = true;
        this.notify();
        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public synchronized void release() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("release " + rCount++);
        notify();
        while (!this.signal) {
            wait();
        }
        this.signal = false;
    }
}
```

How did I imagine execution of this program?:

time 0:   thread1: `sender.start()` ->...->

```
public synchronized void take() {
        System.out.println("take " + sCount++);
        this.signal = true;
        this.notify(); //try wake up waiting threads but noone sleep thus have not affect
        try {
            wait(); // release monitor and await notify
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Thus I see in screen `take 1`

time 300: thread 2 `receiver.start();` ->

```
 public synchronized void release() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("release " + rCount++);  //section is rid thus this lines outputes
        notify(); // notify thread1
        while (!this.signal) {
            wait(); // pass the control to thread1 and await notification .....
        }
        this.signal = false;
    }
```

Thus I didn't expect to see  `release 2`

Please clarify my misunderstanding.

Comment: It is perfectly possible for `release()` to be called first, and completing successfully (since `signal` is initialised to `false`), then `take()` runs and then `release()` again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set `signal = false` *after* the `wait()`.

Sequence of events.

1. `sender` calls `take()`
2. `sender` prints
3. `signal` is set to `true`
4. `receiver` is notified
5. `sender` calls `wait()`
6. `receiver` wakes
7. `receiver` prints
8. `sender` is notified
9. `signal` is `true` so no `wait()`
10. `signal` is set to `false`
11. `release()` method ends
12. `receiver` loops
13. `receiver` prints
14. `signal` is `false` so `wait()`
15. `sender` wakes and exits immediately as nothing to do

So you have several issues

1. Your `sender` doesn't loop
2. You set `signal` at the wrong time

Comment: @gstackoverflow that is irrelevant. The flag has been set so when the receiver does exist it runs as described. Further, you have no guarantee that it doesn't exist.

Comment: @gstackoverflow `8` was a typo - supposed to be `sender`.